# Joinable thread in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/joinable/

> A thread object is joinable if it represents a **thread of execution**.
>
> A thread object is not joinable in any of these cases:
>
> ```
> if it was **default-constructed**.
> if it has been **moved from** (either constructing another thread object, or assigning to it).
> if either of its members join or detach has been called.
> ```

- What is the meaning of default constructed, here?
- W.R.T moved from - When we have to put threads in a vector, we may create thread objects outside and then move them in the vector. Is this one of the cases which this moved from is referring to?
- After detach has been called once, can we never join it again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the meaning of default constructed, here?

It means a std::thread which was constructed with no arguments, and therefore does not represent a thread (i.e. it is not "running").  See docs: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread

> W.R.T moved from - When we have to put threads in a vector, we may create thread objects outside and then move them in the vector. Is this one of the cases which this moved from is referring to?

Yes, you cannot join a thread after moving it into the vector.  But you can of course join the new thread object inside the vector (where it was "moved to").

> After detach has been called once, can we never join it again?

That's right, you cannot join a thread which has already been joined or detached.

Comment: Would be useful to clarify that the second point is not unique to threads.